# What does "seen" mean on user profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

like:

> seen    12 mins ago

This means the profile was viewed 12 mins ago, or the last time the user take action on the website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That means the last time activity was seen on the account (action on the website).

Comment: What is action/activity?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: When you get some action, you know it. ;-)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Loading a page on the site (while logged in), submitting a form, that sort of thing.

Comment: It should be noted that editing a question/answer does *not* count as activity. I lost my "consecutive days seen" because I worked on a question for over a day without checking on my profile or looking at other questions.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/account-last-activity-time-is-not-always-updated/33310#33310) at meta.SO it stands for any activity, but it is updated at most once in 30 minutes. (My guess is that the frequency has been increased since then.)

More relevant meta.SO threads:

- [What determines when a user was "seen"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34003/what-determines-when-a-user-was-seen)
- [A user "seen" 12mins ago but posted a question 9 mins ago. How?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/a-user-seen-12mins-ago-but-posted-a-question-9-mins-ago-how)
- [Is "seen" working ok?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136843/is-seen-working-ok)
- You can find more questions on this topic, if you search for [seen+ago+profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=seen+ago+profile).

Comment: nonono. I saw a lot of seen in 5 min status.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your comment. But if you are asking about this: Suppose you are spending almost all time on the site. If it works as described in the above link, the timestamp is updated once in 30 minutes to the current time. So your "last seen" is cyclically changed from "just now" to "30 minutes ago" .

Comment: oh. so my activity is right 12 minutes before the update time, then i would be seen 12 min ago. okay, cool.